# Error: data is undefined. How is this solved?

Tags: javascript

as it says in the title, I get this error when I click the button to save the form data and then I try to recover it through the DNI, the fact is that after many changes I cannot find out why this omits the error.

more exactly this is what gives me the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: datos is not defined

guardar file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/EJER formulario/finalizar.js:37
```

Now I pass the code in the part where I think the error occurs, which is in the function called "save". As its name indicates, it saves the form data once it has been validated and with the retrieve function, prints them in another window by writing your ID.

```
function guardar() {

    
    document.getElementById('nombre').value = datos.nombre;
    document.getElementById('email').value = datos.email ;
    document.getElementById('edad').value = datos.edad;
    document.getElementById('etsex').value = datos.etsex;
    document.getElementById('tlf').value = datos.tlf;
    document.getElementById('estado_civil').value = datos.estado_civil;
    document.getElementById('seleccion').value = datos.seleccion;
    document.getElementById('txtdesc').value = datos.txtdesc;

    


    sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI, JSON.stringify(datos));

    
    datos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI));



}
    
    function recuperar(){
        console.log("entra");
        var guardaDNI = document.getElementById('guardaDNI').value;
    
        if(sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI)){
            console.log("Pilla el item")
            var datos = sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI);
            console.log(datos.modalidad);
        }else{
            window.alert("No hay datos del DNI : "+guardaDNI);
            document.getElementById('guardaDNI').value = "";
        }
    
    }

function recuperar(){
    var options = "top = 100, left = 100, width = 800px , height= 900px";
    var new_wind;
    new_wind = window.open("","info", options);
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;

    var id = document.getElementById("dni");
    id.value
    var idmsg = "Tu DNI es: "+ document.getElementById("dni").value;

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var edad = document.getElementById("edad").value;

    var asx = document.getElementsByName("sexual");
    var sx;
    for(var i=0;i<asx.length;i++){
        if(asx[i].checked ){
            sx = asx[i].value;
        }
    }

    var tlf = document.getElementById("tlf").value;


    var reg = document.getElementById("estado_civil");
    var estado_civil = reg.options[reg.selectedIndex].value;

    var select = document.getElementsByName("seleccion");
    var sel = [];
    var seleccion = "";
    for(var i=0;i<select.length-1;i++){
        if(select[i].checked){
            sel.push(select[i].value);
            
        }
    }

    for(var i=0;i<sel.length;i++){
        if(select[5].checked){
            if(i<sel.length){
                seleccion += sel[i]+", ";
            }else if(i==sel.length){
                seleccion +=sel[i];
            }
        }else{
            if(i<sel.length){
                seleccion += sel[i]+", ";
            }else if(i==sel.length-1){
                seleccion +=" y "+ sel[i]+".";
            }
        }
            
    }

    if(select.checked){
        seleccion +=" y "+ document.getElementById("extra").value+".";
    }

    var descripcion = document.getElementById("txtdesc").value;
    
    new_wind.document.write("<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='style/style.css'></head><body><div id='result'><div id='flote'>"+
        "<h1>info:</h1><br><hr>Tu nombre es: "+nombre+"<br>"+idmsg+
        "<br>Tu email es: "+email+"<br>Tu sexo es: "+sx +"<br>Tu edad: "+edad+
        "<br>Tu teléfono de contacto: "+tlf+
        "<br>Su estado civil es: "+estado_civil+"<br>Acepto las cookies: "+seleccion+
        "<br>Por último lo que escribio es lo siguiente: "+descripcion+"</div></div></body></html>"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add `var` before `datos`

```
function guardar(var datos) {
```

Comment: I put that and now ask me declare the parametre. I don't think that's the right way to do it @Asif